# how to use Touch ID with respective to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, touch-id

I have integrated Touch id into my app and the process starts as below -

1.When User launches the App , View Will appear method in Authenticaion.m will be called and then it asks the user to authenticate using touch ID and shows a alert dialog with "Enter Password" & "Cancel".

2.If this is the User's first time logging in , he will choose to authenticate using his finger and then the Login.m will be shown where there are username & password text field where he has to enter his credentials to login.

3.He can also choose "Enter Password" or "Cancel" which will take him into the login.m where he will enter his username and password to authenticate.

4.If the user logs into the application and quits the application from the background state and tries to login into the app then as he didn't logout of the application , he will be shown the same view will appear method where if he authenticates using his finger for touch id , he doesn't need to enter his username and password for authentication and he directly to logs in , now the other case is if he again choose to "Enter Password" or press "Cancel" he will be taken to the login.m file where he has to enter the username and password .

5.If the user logs into the app with any of the above ways and logs out of the app and again tried to login, all the process from step 1 is repeated . I want to achieve the above functionality.

My DOUBT is that in the success block of LAContext , how do i need to store the NSUserDefaults for txtUsername & txtPassword so that the app recognizes that user didn't logout from the app and once he removes the app from the background and again tried to login and uses his finger he will directly be logged into the app. please see the below code i am using in authentication.m and login.m . please let me know how to solve this as i am struggling from past week to solve this case .

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

dispatch_queue_t highPriorityQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.75 * NSEC_PER_SEC), highPriorityQueue, ^{

LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Please Authenticate To Proceed";
if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {

    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

                            if (success) {

                NSString *result = (NSString *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"txtUserName"];

                                SignInViewController *user = [[SignInViewController alloc]init];

                                if ([result isEqualToString:@"rthottempudi" ] ) {

                                  NSLog(@"User is authenticated successfully");

                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



                                        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                                                    @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                                        ViewController *congoView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CongratsViewController"];
                                        [self presentViewController:congoView animated:YES completion:nil];


                                    });

                                }

                                else{

                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication Failed"
                                                                                        message:@"PLease Try Again"
                                                                                       delegate:self
                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                    [alertView show];


                                      NSLog(@"failed");
                                        });
                                }
                        }





                            else {

                                switch (error.code) {
                                    case LAErrorAuthenticationFailed:
                                    {

                                        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication Failed"
                                                                                            message:@"Please Try Again"
                                                                                           delegate:self
                                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                        [alertView show];
                                        NSLog(@"Authentication Failed");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case LAErrorUserCancel:
                                    {
                                        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                                                    @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                                        SignInViewController *congoView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
                                        [self presentViewController:congoView animated:YES completion:nil];

                                        NSLog(@"User pressed Cancel button");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case LAErrorUserFallback:
                                    {
                                        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                                                    @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                                        SignInViewController *congoView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
                                        [self presentViewController:congoView animated:YES completion:nil];

                                        NSLog(@"User pressed \"Enter Password\"");
                                        break;
                                    }




                                    default:
                                        NSLog(@"Touch ID is not configured");
                                        break;
                                }

                                NSLog(@"Authentication Fails");
                            }
                        }];
}
else {
    // if the device doesn't have touch id
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                    @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        SignInViewController *congoView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:congoView animated:YES completion:nil];



    });


}

   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't store private data on UserDefaults,

Instead of that store username and password at keychain, store TouchIDEnabled value (true/false) at UserDefaults.

And if TouchIdEnabled is true, ask for touchId.

If touchID success, read username-password from keychain.